# Magento Fetch all images from database

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, entity-attribute-value

I have been searching for the query to get the image urls (all the ones in image gallery, not just small/thumbnail images) for the products. I found this query

```
select * from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg, catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv, catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev WHERE mg.value_id =mgv.value_id AND mg.entity_id = ev.entity_id AND ev.attribute_id IN (85,86,87) AND mgv.position = 1
```

But this is not working with magento 1.4. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The following sql instruction shows the path of base_image, small_image, and thumbnail image.

```
SELECT  `a`.`entity_id`,  `a`.`sku`, `b`.`value` AS `base_image`, `a`.`small_image`,  `a`.`thumbnail` FROM `catalog_product_flat_10` a, 
`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` b WHERE a.entity_id = b.entity_id LIMIT 1000;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick for Magento 2

```
SELECT e.entity_id AS 'id',
       e.sku AS 'sku',
       v2.value AS 'image',
       v3.value AS 'thumbnail',
       v4.value AS 'small image',
       mg.value AS 'media_gallery'
FROM catalog_product_entity e
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar v2 ON e.entity_id = v2.row_id
AND v2.store_id = 0
AND v2.attribute_id =
  (SELECT attribute_id
   FROM eav_attribute
   WHERE attribute_code = 'image'
     AND entity_type_id =
       (SELECT entity_type_id
        FROM eav_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar v3 ON e.entity_id = v3.row_id
AND v3.store_id = 0
AND v3.attribute_id =
  (SELECT attribute_id
   FROM eav_attribute
   WHERE attribute_code = 'thumbnail'
     AND entity_type_id =
       (SELECT entity_type_id
        FROM eav_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar v4 ON e.entity_id = v4.row_id
AND v4.store_id = 0
AND v4.attribute_id =
  (SELECT attribute_id
   FROM eav_attribute
   WHERE attribute_code = 'small_image'
     AND entity_type_id =
       (SELECT entity_type_id
        FROM eav_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT m1.value_id AS m1_value_id, GROUP_CONCAT(m2.value) AS VALUE, m2.value_id AS m2_value_id, m1.row_id AS m1_row_id
   FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value m1
   INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery m2 ON m2.value_id = m1.value_id
   AND m2.attribute_id =
     (SELECT attribute_id
      FROM eav_attribute
      WHERE attribute_code = 'media_gallery'
        AND entity_type_id =
          (SELECT entity_type_id
           FROM eav_entity_type
           WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
   GROUP BY m1.row_id) mg ON e.entity_id = m1_row_id
WHERE e.sku IN
(
"sku1",
"sku2",
"sku3"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try for example to get small images path

```
select * from catalog_product_entity_varchar
where entity_id = 20 /*Optional your attribute*/
and attribute_id  = 86 ;/*small image*/
```

the field value will show you the specific path of the image

for example C:\wamp\www\magento\media\catalog\product\ **value** (field from catalog_product_entity_varchar)

if you want to find other image you should check the table eav_attribute

Comment: Hi, I ask for all the images that are uploaded to the magento with the product skus(Gallery images, small/thumbnail images). If we could able to get those image urls that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Just piggybacking off Chen's awesome answer (which has helped me get somewhere I needed to get to, thanks bud!)

```
SELECT  `a`.`entity_id`,  `a`.`sku`, 
concat('https://yoururl/media/catalog/product',`b`.`value`) AS `base_image`, 
concat('https://yoururl/media/catalog/product',`a`.`small_image`) AS `small_image`,  
concat('https://yoururl/media/catalog/product',`a`.`thumbnail`) AS `thumbnail`, 
group_concat(concat('https://yoururl/media/catalog/product', `b`.`value`)) AS `additional_images` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` a, 
`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` b WHERE a.entity_id = b.entity_id
GROUP BY `a`.`sku`;
```

You can group_concat by the value and by SKU to get a juicy additional images column.

I know we're way past M1 support, but hopefully this can help someone.